# Add field on php from paste table

Tags: php, forms

i have a field on my form called itens, i have a button to add more fields to the itens but what i want is Ctrl+V and paste a list from word or what ever program, and the fields will be automatically created with the pasted content.

Any ideas?

```html
<html><head
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/asset/img/favicon.ico">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->




    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="/bundles/c588c3c0468f4633c99de6e16289c863.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div></div></head>
<body class="demo-bootstrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="demoContainer" style="height: auto">
                <form id="surveyForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal fv-form fv-form-bootstrap" novalidate="novalidate"><button type="submit" class="fv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Question</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input class="form-control" name="question" data-fv-field="question" type="text"><i style="display: none;" class="form-control-feedback" data-fv-icon-for="question"></i>
        <small style="display: none;" class="help-block" data-fv-validator="notEmpty" data-fv-for="question" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED">The question required and cannot be empty</small></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Options</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input class="form-control" name="option[]" data-fv-field="option[]" type="text"><i style="display: none;" class="form-control-feedback" data-fv-icon-for="option[]"></i>
        <small style="display: none;" class="help-block" data-fv-validator="notEmpty" data-fv-for="option[]" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED">The option required and cannot be empty</small><small style="display: none;" class="help-block" data-fv-validator="stringLength" data-fv-for="option[]" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED">The option must be less than 100 characters long</small></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The option field template containing an option field and a Remove button -->
    <div class="form-group hide has-feedback" id="optionTemplate">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-5">
            <input class="form-control" name="option[]" data-fv-field="option[]" type="text"><i style="display: none;" class="form-control-feedback" data-fv-icon-for="option[]"></i>
        <small style="display: none;" class="help-block" data-fv-validator="notEmpty" data-fv-for="option[]" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED">The option required and cannot be empty</small><small style="display: none;" class="help-block" data-fv-validator="stringLength" data-fv-for="option[]" data-fv-result="NOT_VALIDATED">The option must be less than 100 characters long</small></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The maximum number of options
    var MAX_OPTIONS = 5;

    $('#surveyForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                question: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The question required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                'option[]': {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The option required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 100,
                            message: 'The option must be less than 100 characters long'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        // Add button click handler
        .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            var $template = $('#optionTemplate'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .insertBefore($template),
                $option   = $clone.find('[name="option[]"]');

            // Add new field
            $('#surveyForm').formValidation('addField', $option);
        })

        // Remove button click handler
        .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            var $row    = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                $option = $row.find('[name="option[]"]');

            // Remove element containing the option
            $row.remove();

            // Remove field
            $('#surveyForm').formValidation('removeField', $option);
        })

        // Called after adding new field
        .on('added.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            // data.field   --> The field name
            // data.element --> The new field element
            // data.options --> The new field options

            if (data.field === 'option[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="option[]"]').length >= MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        })

        // Called after removing the field
        .on('removed.field.fv', function(e, data) {
           if (data.field === 'option[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="option[]"]').length < MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addButton').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#surveyForm')
        .on('added.field.fv removed.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            var $body  = $('body'),
                $iframe = $body.data('iframe.fv');
            if ($iframe) {
                // Adjust the height of iframe
                $iframe.height($body.height());
            }
        });
});
</script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O9jC.png)

What i want is copy this list from word like example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFWt5.png)

and the itens will be on its field automatically

Comment: This question is super vague and extremely broad. There's a billion ways you might do this, and we've got no idea which ones might work because you've given very little detail on your actual situation.

Comment: Sorry for that i explained my self better now.

Comment: There is a [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) event which might help.